# React Route is not working, I just get a blank screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I know its my routes because if I take them out my Navbar will appear. I'm trying to follow a previous example I did when I was in my coding bootcamp, I can't see any differences.
Here is my App.jsx code

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navbar } from "./compnents/navbar";
import { Home } from "./views/Home";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <Navbar />
      </header>
      
        

      
      <main classNameName="container mt-4">
  
      <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}/>
            </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    
       
   </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

and my main.jsx

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { App } from './App';
import './index.css';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

and finally my Home.jsx

```
export const Home = () => {
    
    return (
        <>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        </>

    
    
  );
}
```

Comment: This usually means that you have an error in the console

Comment: is element a valid prop? didnt see it in the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrapped BrowserRouter around App at your Main, no need to do it again at your App.js component